# HOMO and LUMO energy levels diagrams

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, software, cheminformatics

Good time of day. I want to draw the same beautiful pictures in my work as I will attach below taking from some articles. Are there any programms or scripts which can do this? I would be glad if someone shared their scripts.
[image]

[image]

Thank you for your time!